# Passing parameter to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a large layout file containing two fragments: A list fragment and a detail fragment. List fragment should list different data based on the TYPE parameter passed to Activity. Problem is that when I call setContentView() method in Activity's onCreate() method, fragments create and I have no way to pass this parameter to it.
Code:

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
Type type;
MyListFragment listFragment;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(Constants.KEY_TYPE)) {
        int type = extras.getInt(Constants.KEY_TYPE);
        type = Type.getTypeByValue(type);
    }

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        // Normal Screen Layout
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        listFragment = new MyListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, listFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Large Screen layout
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        listFragment = (MyListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.listFragment);
    }

}
```

If I `new` the activity, I can call a method on its onAttach() method to get the parameter but in this example I have defined Fragments inside xml layout and they initialize when activity creates. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Bundle` and pass it to the fragment with the `setArguments()` function. Then this `Bundle` is available from the `getArguments()` function.

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()